# styling child html elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I need to style some child elements in the dom but only if they are not a child of a specific element.  as an example i need to bold the text in the span in this

```
<span class="a">
 <span class="b">
  <span class="c">
    bold this test
  </span>
 </span>
</span>
```

but not in this

```
<span class="a">
 <a class="SomeOtherclass">
  <span class="b">
   <span class="c">
    not bold
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
</span>
```

I dont have control of the output so i cannot change the class names or structure

Comment: What are the exact conditions? That is, when should the text be bold? As soon as you can specify that, it’s mostly just a matter of writing a CSS selector, or set of selectors. – Note that in the given code, the element in class `c` is in both case a child of an element in class `b`, so this appears to be about some more complicated relationship than simple parent–child.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the direct descendant selector `>`. The selector `a > b` will select `b` only if it is a *direct* descendant (ie. child) of `a`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/LfhXT/)

```
.a > .b > .c {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the question as it stands, but I also think that not all use-cases have been revealed in the question. That's no fault of yours, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is Right

and if you need **second option** than

**you can do this**

```
.c{
font-weight:bold;
}

.SomeOtherclass .c{
font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an overriding rule for the special case, so for example:

```
.c {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.SomeOtherClass .c {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I have assumed that in the normal case, you don't always have the a, b, c nesting - which is why you are asking to apply this rule except in a particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Child-of selector** for it...

For example,

```
.a { /*Your Style*/ }
.a > .b { /*Your Style*/ }
.a > .b > .c { /*Your Style*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for this is

```
span.a>a.SomeOtherclass>span.b>span.c{
  font-weight: bold
}
```

this will be applied to the particular class of particular parent only. Not in the other case.

if you want to reverse it, then it will be like this

```
span.a>span.b>span.c{
  font-weight: bold
}
```

it will not be applied in case of you add anything(any tag) in between this hierarchy of DOM.

This will do .. :)